# Change SSH Jump Host based on host name prefix/suffix

Tags: ssh

I want to access a few very similar machines that are on a private network: `A`, `B`, `C`. I have configured a JumpHost `J1`, and set the config for these to use it:

```
Host J1
    HostName 123.123.123.123
    User ciprian

Host A B C
    HostName %h
    User ciprian
    ProxyJump J1
    LocalForward 8501 localhost:8501
```

Now I am setting up a second JumpHost, `J2`, and would like to connect to the same machines through either `J1` or `J2`. Is there a way to write the config file such that if the machine has `J1` in the name, it would jump through `J1`, or if it has `J2`, it would jump through `J2`?
Of course, without manually specifying exact matches :)

I can write the config like this:

```
# ...
Host *-J1
    ProxyJump J1

Host *-J2
    ProxyJump J2

Host A* B* C*
    # --- Which Host name? ---
    User ciprian
    # ...
```

so if I give `ssh A-J1`, it would pick up the settings to jump through J1. However, when it parses the definition related to `A*`, I can no longer specify the `HostName`, since `%h` would resolve to `A-J1`, and I would like it to resolve to just `A`.

I believe that some magic can be accomplished with `CanonicalizeHostName` and `CanonicalizePermittedCNAMEs`, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: "I want to access a few very similar machines" – "A few", so "not many", right? Then what's wrong in `Host A-*`/`HostName A`, `Host B-*`/`HostName B` and `Host C-*`/`HostName C`? I think the common config (`User ciprian` etc.) can still be under `Host A-* B-* C-*`.

Comment: yes, I could write them out. But you know, the urge to optimize and not repeat, hoping to learn something in the process :)

Answer (score 0):

You can using ProxyCommand and some minor shell script:

```
Host *-prefix1
   ProxyCommand ssh -q jump1 'H="%h"; nc ${H%%-prefix1} %p || echo "ProxyCommand failed! >&2"'

Host *-prefix2
   ProxyCommand ssh -q jump2 'H="%h"; nc ${H%%-prefix2} %p || echo "ProxyCommand failed! >&2"'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is different from ProxyJump